# IndVal on R (indicator species from labdsv)

Tags: r

I have loaded labdsv package on R and I am trying to run indval following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mExObdyuVbw

When I put `iva <- indval(A.only, B$Location)`, based on my data names, I keep onb getting the error:

> Error in indval.default(A.only, B$Location) : 
>     All species must occur in at least one plot

I have checked a couple of times that species without any data (that is all 0) have been removed in my table).

Any idea what is causing that error and how do I proceed to the the indicator values?

Comment: Welcome! Please make this question reproducible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The title of your question is not enough descriptive on my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I started by removing species (columns) with nothing there

```
mydata2 <- mydata[ , which(!apply(mydata==0,2,all))]
```

I still had the same error. The issue was that some species columns had NAs, so I changed these to zero.

```
mydata2[is.na(mydata2)] <- 0
```

It worked fine after that.